# Contar pares de palavras em uma tabela e gerar uma tabela de contagem no R

Tags: r, tabela-html, dplyr

Eu tenho uma tabela no seguinte formato:

[tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFvLa.jpg)

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| a | b |
| b | a |
| c | d |
| e | f |
| g | f |

E preciso contar quantas vezes cada par aparece, ainda que em uma ordem diferente.
Consegui usar o pacote widyr e a função pairwise_count. No entanto, combinações iguais mas em ordem diferente são considerados como diferentes. Como removo essa redundância da minha tabela?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(widyr)

x <- read.csv(file = "table.csv", sep = ",")

df <- data.frame(x)

y <- pairwise_count(df, "Source", "Target")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eis uma solução.

1. Comece por, em cada linha, ordenar os dois valores e juntá-los com `paste`;
2. de seguida crie a permutação desse vetor de pares que os ponha em ordem, para repor a ordem original mais tarde;
3. agora o `table` conta os pares. Mas como os põe em ordem alfabética precisamos do último passo;
4. a permutação do vetor composta com a transformação inversa, `order(i)`, dá a identidade, ou seja, a ordem original das colunas.

```r
pares <- apply(dados, 1, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))
i <- order(pares)
contagens <- table(pares)

dados$contagens <- rep(contagens, contagens)[order(i)]
dados
#>    Source Target contagens
#> 1       d      a         2
#> 2       c      c         1
#> 3       c      a         1
#> 4       d      b         3
#> 5       d      b         3
#> 6       c      e         1
#> 7       a      d         2
#> 8       e      d         1
#> 9       b      d         3
#> 10      e      e         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Dados de teste

```r
set.seed(2022)

dados <- data.frame(
  Source = sample(letters[1:5], 10, TRUE),
  Target = sample(letters[1:5], 10, TRUE)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada! Consegui resolver essa questão! Sua ajuda foi muito útil!